# How can I order the output of my long LINQ query by a double and then a string?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ query:

```
summaries = from m in _master
                            join d in _detail on pk + m.RowKey equals d.PartitionKey into outer
                            from d in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            select new
                            {
                                Position = m.Position,
                                Title = m.Title,
                                Detail = ((d == null) ? 0 : 1),
                                PartitionKey = m.PartitionKey,
                                RowKey = m.RowKey,
                                Modified = m.Modified,
                                ModifiedBy = m.ModifiedBy
                            } into split
                            group split by split.Title into g
                            select new AdminSummary
                            {
                                Position = g.Last().Position,
                                Title = g.Key,
                                DetailCount = g.Sum(s => s.Detail),
                                PartitionKey = g.Last().PartitionKey,
                                RowKey = g.Last().RowKey,
                                Modified = g.Last().Modified,
                                ModifiedBy = g.Last().ModifiedBy
                            };
```

The query works well but now I would like to do an order by on Position (double) followed by Title (string).

Can someone advise how I can do this?

Can someone tell me how to do the order by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy:

```
summaries = summaries.OrderBy(item =>item.Position).ThenBy(item =>item.Title);
```

Also you can use `OrderByDescending()` and `ThenByDescending()` if you need them in descending order

Answer (score 1):

Do this after your above query.

```
summaries = from s in summaries
            orderby s.Position,s.Title
            select s
```